# Flag difference in a string variable in SQL

Tags: string, difference, calculation

I have data as:
[Image of data I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mikpw.png)
I want to add flag variables in the data as:
[Image of data I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBNk9.png)
I have tried the lag function but it didn't work due to the variable being character.

I want to flag any change in string variable.Please help.

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure you have read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question in order to get an answer. As of now, it is totally unclear 1) what programming language you use 2) what exactly you want to achieve 3) what you have tried (code) and 4) what exactly isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the query along the lines of:

CREATE TEMP TABLE WANT AS(
SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) != NAME
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS FLAG1
FROM DATA_HAVE 
ORDER BY 
ID);

No judging, just sharing.